# how does rails differentiate the method for the same url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I am new in rails,and I create the first rails application (Blog) follow the guide at [rails's docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) step by step.

However when I run the application,I found something I can not understand.

http://localhost:3000/posts/2

With `GET` method,this will return the details of post whose id is 2.

But when update this post,I found the action of the form is '/posts/2'.

When delete the post,I found rails create a form element in the body with action '/posts/2' and method `POST`,so I wonder how does rails know update or delete this post?

Since I do not found any condition word in the post controller.

Anyone can tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which action is run is determined by a unique combination of the **path** and the **verb**

Do the command `rake routes` in your app folder, and you'll see a list of routes.

Paths, are the RESTful routes to your resources.

Verbs are `GET` `POST` `DELETE`, and `PUT`

I would also recommend the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) as reading, which explains this in a lot more detail.

Here's sample output from `rake routes` from one of my apps:

```
      path name|verb  |path                              |action
============================================================================
    alias_lists GET    /alias_lists(.:format)             alias_lists#index
                POST   /alias_lists(.:format)             alias_lists#create
 new_alias_list GET    /alias_lists/new(.:format)         alias_lists#new
edit_alias_list GET    /alias_lists/:id/edit(.:format)    alias_lists#edit
     alias_list GET    /alias_lists/:id(.:format)         alias_lists#show
                PUT    /alias_lists/:id(.:format)         alias_lists#update
                DELETE /alias_lists/:id(.:format)         alias_lists#destroy
```

Note that `show`, `update` and `destroy` all have the same path, but a different verb.

```
show's verb    = GET
update's verb  = PUT
destroy's verb = DELETE
```

Comment: Its all in your routes.rb. Nice answer @normalocity

Comment: But for path `/posts/2`,the verbs is `POST`,both the path and verb are the same. How does rails know to delete or update the post 2?

Comment: The verbs are not the same for `destroy` and `update`. The `destroy` action takes the `DELETE` verb and the `update` action takes the `PUT` verb. I've updated my answer with some samples. If your `rake routes` output doesn't look very similar to what I've posted above, then please post it in your question so we can see what you're talking about. We would also need to see the code in `config/routes.rb`